# Migrating app from Android to iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, ios

I have an app deployed in Android, I wish to create the same app for iOS also. Is migrating possible using tool like Phonegap.(Phonegap does not support Java.) that would help me in deploying my app to iOS also.

Comment: Are you using phonegap in your android app or have you written code in java ?

Comment: I have already written my app in Java.

Comment: If it is only a java app try with this [link](http://code.google.com/p/j2objc/)

Answer (score 0):

if you have developed by java means we wont convert it into the ios directly . have to develop apps using sdk's like Titanium, flex etc.

Answer (score 0):

No.you cannot.Phonegap will only supprt HTML,CSS and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Migrate the android to iPhone there is no any option to directly migrate the native app of the android to iPhone for that i you need to develop application in cross platform so you can create the build of the iPhone.